# REST API for codeigniter 2.0.1

Tags: codeigniter, rest, codeigniter-restserver

codeigniter-restserver is available for codeigniter 2.1.0 or above

(https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver)

but unable to find REST API for codeigniter 2.0.1

How to create restserver in codeigniter 2.0.1

Answer (score 5):

You can download from **GitHub** archives:

I found the last compatible version that CodeIgniter-RestServer v2.4. Version 2.5 is for CodeIgniter 2.0.3 and higher.

CodeIgniter Reactor 2.0 (for 1.7.x support download v2.2 from Downloads tab)

**GitHub Page:** https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver/tree/v2.4

Comment: In this version we don't give us the possibility to use  function for setting up http_user_session `_check_login`