# Create REST API Endpoints from an Existing PHP CodeIgniter Project

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I have a web application built on `PHP CodeIgniter 2.1.3` and `MySql`. I know this is an old framework. However, I wonder if there's a quick way to create API Endpoints from this existing project. My ultimate goal is to create a new web application that decouples the front and back ends and moves away from the MVC model.

Comment: In the new version (CI4), that’s very easy thanks to the response/requests/rest built-in features. I am afraid you will have to find external REST api/routing projects by yourself on GitHub but most of them are for CI3.

Comment: Maybe this one? https://github.com/atishhamte/rest-server-codeigniter-2.2.x or here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803009/rest-api-for-codeigniter-2-0-1